# Multiplying the PV$(\frac{1}{x})$ by $x$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I am trying to show that $x\text{PV}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 1$ in the sense of distributions, that is $\langle x\text{PV}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), \phi \rangle = \langle 1, \phi \rangle$ for all $\phi$, where PV denotes the Cauchy Principle Value, and $\phi$ is a test function. Is the following correct?

$\langle x\text{PV}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), \phi \rangle = \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0} \displaystyle\int_{|x| > \epsilon} x \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \phi \ dx $.

If this is not the correct approach, what is?

edit:

So apparently the result is an immediate consequence of the definitions:

$\langle x\text{PV}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), \phi \rangle = \langle \text{PV}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), x \phi \rangle = \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0} \displaystyle\int_{|x| > \epsilon} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) (x\phi) \ dx = \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi \ dx = \langle 1, \phi \rangle$.

Comment: Yes.$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: You tacitly interchanged the $x$ with the $PV$ operator.  Better, would be to note that $$\langle x\,PV\left(\frac1x\right),\phi \rangle =\langle PV\left(\frac1x\right),x\,\phi \rangle =\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{|x|>\epsilon}\frac1x \,(x\phi(x))\,dx$$

Comment: That is a good point.